# Access variable IBAction

Tags: swift, ibaction

I need help my function doesn't access my boolean. My switch IBAction is suppose to change it but doesn't seem to update that variable in my second file.

```
@IBAction func saveClubSwitchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "ClubState")
   if(sender.isOn == true)
    {
        clubSwitchBool = true
         print(stateClubSwitchBool())
    }else
    {
      clubSwitchBool = false
        print(stateClubSwitchBool())
    }
}
   func stateClubSwitchBool() -> Bool
{
    return clubSwitchBool
}
```

This is my function that access my boolean in another file:

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    var clubSwitchBool1 = getSwitchBool()
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this link helps me but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Can you show the definition of getSwitchBool() method?

Comment: func getSwitchBool() -> Bool
 {
  
   return ReglagesVC().clubSwitchBool
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you declare/initialize the clubSwitchBool variable?

You can simplify your function but having clubSwitchBool read the isOn attribute.

```
@IBAction func saveClubSwitchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "ClubState")
    clubSwitchBool = sender.isOn
    print(stateClubSwitchBool())
}
```

**EDIT:**

Have your clubSwitchBool1 read from UserDefaults:

```
clubSwitchBool1 = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ClubState")
```

Comment: var clubSwitchBool = false

initialise in the file were the UISwitch and IBAction are
The problem is that clubSwitchBool1 is always false

Comment: You said you are accessing it from another file. I suppose the Switch and the variable are in the view ? Maybe the View isn't initialized properly ... Can you post more code?

Comment: posting more code might confuse more than help, my question might not be precise enough : my IBAction is a void, it returns nothing, so my boolean variable isn't saved, when my function accesses it it will always be the value i initialized it (false). I want to know how my switch can change my Boolean variable (the function in other file aren't important here, just change it it the current file its own)

Comment: In that case the code above is correct. Whenever the switch changes, the saveClubSwitchPressed will be called. Did you connect the UISwitch to the IBAction?

Comment: i did the problem is that IBAction you use is a void, the value of the boolean is changed only in the functions called inside. Fact is I need the values permanently change out of the class. maybe a addtarget?

Comment: Have your clubSwitchBool1 read from UserDefaults. See my edited answer. It's hard to help without knowing the architecture of your controllers ...

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
class ReglagesVC: UIViewController
{
    var clubSwitchBool = false

    @IBAction func saveClubSwitchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch)
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "ClubState")
        clubSwitchBool = sender.isOn
        print(stateClubSwitchBool())
    }

    func stateClubSwitchBool() -> Bool
    {
        return clubSwitchBool
    }
}
```

is the same as yours. And it is working perfectly fine.

Now the function that you are using:

```
func getSwitchBool() -> Bool
{
    return ReglagesVC().clubSwitchBool
}
```

In the above method call you are using `ReglagesVC()` that always creates a new instance of `ReglagesVC`. Now everytime you access `clubSwitchBool` of the newly created instance, it will return `false`.

That is the reason you are getting `false` everytime.

Comment: Post more code, i.e what is flow of your 2 controllers and in which class you have created getSwitchBool() so that I can help you further.

Comment: `class MapVC: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, GMUClusterManagerDelegate{func getSwitchBool() -> Bool
 {
  
   return ReglagesVC().clubSwitchBool
 }
}`

Comment: I understand your answer thank you, but how do I fetch this boolean value from my ReglagesVC file to my loadView (MapVC file)

Comment: You need to store the instance of ReglagesVC and then access clubSwitchBool value or you can use UserDefault to fetch value.

Comment: You accept the answers that find the issue with your code code and give a solution. Anyways all the best.